# bot.send_photo возвращает ошибку

Tags: python-2.x, telegram-bot

Добрый день.

Телеграм бот, почему-то, перестал посылать фотографию в чат.

```
img = open('/home/pi/myimage.jpg')
bot.send_photo(CHAT_ID,img)
```

Выдает:

```
TypeError: send_photo() takes exactrly 1 argument (3 given)
```

еще вчера все работало. Не могу понять, в какую сторону копать.

```
bot.send_message(CHAT_ID,'test')
```

работает

Comment: копать в сторону библиотеки, которая работает с апи, пробовали?

Comment: `img = open('myimage.jpg', 'rb')` (след. строка) `bot.send_photo(chat_id, img)`. Попробуйте так